# How to plot datetimes on xaxis at their correct spacing?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas

I am trying to plot the following dates on the x-axis of a scatter plot such that the dates are spaced apart appropriately.

This is what I have tried so far:

In `df` I have the following data:

```
     date str        A
1    06-Jul-13   9.27
2    25-Jul-13   7.55
5    31-Jul-13   18.22
8    27-Aug-13   12.25
11   18-Sep-13   5.80
```

`df.dtypes` returns:

```
date str     object
A    float64
dtype: object
```

Try a few versions of the date column:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

df['date obj'] = df['date str'].apply(parse)
df['date int'] = df['date obj'].astype(np.int64)

# this produces "KeyError: u'no item named date str'"
df.plot(x='date str', y='A', kind='scatter')

# this produces "KeyError: u'no item named date obj'"
df.plot(x='date obj', y='A', kind='scatter')

# this produces correctly spaced dates, but the x-axis labels do not display the dates
df.plot(x='date int', y='A', kind='scatter')
```

How do I get the dates spaced correctly, and keep the appropriate date labels on the x-axis?

Comment: You could try to add the code to create the simplified `df`, so it is easier to try out. ;-)

Comment: df = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv')

Comment: You could then paste a couple of lines of the CSV in the question (and add that line on how you read the data with `read_csv` to the question as well). Then you wont need the "In `df` I have the following data:" part. :-)